# flutter : Exception has occurred. _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value) I use appwrite library

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

if I use :

```
 uid: user!.uid,
```

and try to click the post button in my app this error happened :

```
 Exception has occurred. _TypeError (Null check operator used on a null value)
```

if I try what they say in debug console

```
: Error: Property 'uid' cannot be accessed on 'UserModel?' because it is potentially null.
lib/…/controller/post_controller.dart:106
- 'UserModel' is from 'package:studyv/models/user_model.dart' ('lib/models/user_model.dart').
package:studyv/models/user_model.dart:1
Try accessing using ?. instead.
      uid: user.uid,
                ^^^
```

and write it

```
 uid: user?.uid,
```

this error happened ?:

```
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
```

I will cry!! what should I do when I try to solve it I end up making more errors in my app if someone knows what to do please help !!!!

Comment: Provide how you initialize the user instance it will help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to understand how Dart's null safety works and for that I recommend you read the [docs](https://dart.dev/null-safety).

The first error you had was because you were trying to read an 'uid' property out of a null UserModel Object.

The second error happens because you're trying to set 'uid' (which is of type 'String' - meaning it can't be null) with UserModel's 'uid' which is of type String? (can be null).

```
String? canBeNull;
String cannotBeNull;

// This works because String? let's you take null values
canBeNull = null;
  
// This WILL FAIL because: A value of type 'Null' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
cannotBeNull = null; 

// This will work because if 'canBeNull' is not null, its value will be used, otherwise it will get 'defaultValue'
cannotBeNull = canBeNull ?? 'defaultValue';
```

The best thing you can do is to check if 'user.uid != null'  before making that attribution;

Other option (not ideal) is to do something like this:

```
uid: user?.uid ?? 'some fallback value'
```

This will just make your edit-time errors go away, but it won't solve your problem because apparently your UserModel is getting a null value.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you don't understand the `null safety` in Dart, you have to learn about it.

When you use `uid: user!.uid,` it gives you the error because the `user` instance is null, maybe you didn't initialize it well. And when you use `uid: user?.uid,` it allows you to affect a null to the property `uid`. You have two solutions, **first** is to make sure that you initialized the `user` instance before using it somewhere and use `!.` with it no problem, **second** use `?.` with `??` like this : `uid: user?.uid ?? 'default id here'`. I don't think you should use the second one because it is a user id. so you must use the first one and make sure that the user instance is initialized before you use it. Provide how you initialize it will help figuring a solution for your problem.
to understand more about null safety this [video](https://youtu.be/5Ro-CZ8Msno?si=YnM3iOjLRFg8ynC7) may help.
And don't cry you just need to get things right that’s it.